# a php explain with the_content filter

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

first of all i have this code

```
function Huemix_content_filter_qm($content){
    $item = '\?';
    $before='<span class="kindared">';
    $after='</span>';
    $content = preg_replace("|($item)|","$before$1$after",$content);
    $content = preg_replace("|(<[^>]+?)($before($item)$after)([^<]+?>)|","$1$3$4",$content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'Huemix_content_filter_qm');
```

i can under stand the whole code but this three vars `$1$3$4`
can any one tell me what they are, cuz as i did i never define them !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/preg_replace):

> replacement may contain references of the form \n or (since PHP 4.0.4) **$n, with the latter form being the preferred one. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th parenthesized pattern. n can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0 refers to the text matched by the whole pattern. Opening parentheses are counted from left to right (starting from 1) to obtain the number of the capturing subpattern**. To use backslash in replacement, it must be doubled ("\\" PHP string).

Basically each one represents a match in parenthesis in the regex. The number represents which match it is. `$1` represents what is matched with `(<[^>]+?)`, `$3` matches `($item)`, and `$4` matches `([^<]+?>)`.